# online exam time down counter in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

how to create a down counter in php for an online exam and after the counter reaches 0 it should automatically finish  the exam can i use these code if possible please tell me how

```
    <!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah this code looks fine. Did you tried this code? Got any error?

Comment: it works but the timer starts from (Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25 ) i don't  want to start it from that date i want to start the date from my database

Comment: this code is  working fine. just change the time with examination start time Date("May 25, 2018 11:41:15")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment you need to get the date from your database so just store it in some field and get it in script

```
<input type="hidden" id="dateFromDB" value="<?php echo $dateFromDB;?>">
```

I can't tell how to get date from the database as you haven't mentioned anything about your database in your question. But I hope you know how to. So just store it in the `$dateFromDB`. Get it like this

```
var dateDB = document.getElementById("dateFromDB").val();
```

And use the `dateDB` instead of the static date

```
var countDownDate = new Date(dateDB).getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the strtotime function to get the date:

```
$date = strtotime("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25");
$remaining = $date - time();
```

Then $remaining is the number of seconds remaining. Then you can divide that number to get the number of days, hours, minutes, etc.

```
$daysRemaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
$hoursRemaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
```

To put this into a JavaScript function, it'd look something like this:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        <?php
         /*
        It is important that the date field in the database is the proper datatype,
        i.e. DATETIME.
        The 'date' in this select statement is your date field
        The where clause is the condition of a specific selection in your table
        You then replace the hardcoded date with the data stored as a php variable
        */
        $sql = "SELECT date FROM table WHERE something='something'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $dateData = mysql_fetch_array($result)[0];

        $date = strtotime("".$dateData."");
        $remaining = $date - time();
        $daysRemaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
        $hoursRemaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
        ?>
        var days = <?php echo $daysRemaining; ?>;
        var hours = <?php echo $hoursRemaining; ?>;
        <?php
        if($remaining <= 0) {
            ?>
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
            <?php
        }else {
            ?>
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h ";
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Edit:

After seeing that you need the date from the database, see edited answer.
Change the mysql syntax to fit either mysqli or PDO syntax if that's what you use. I recommend that you use mysqli_ or PDO if you don't already, due to mysql_
being deprecated.

Hope this helps.

A question though. If you know the examination time, what's to stop you from simply just using that time? Anyways, I showed you how to retreive a date from the database.